# SwiftUI: EditButton does not trigger onDelete when embedded within an HStack Section header

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a Form Section which I want to show some text and the `EditButton()` within the same header line as shown below:

[image]

The issue occurs when I tap the button whenever its embedded within an HStack. The button text toggles between "Edit" and "Done", yet it doesn't call the `onDelete()` action for the rows. However, it does work if it's solely assigned as the header, footer, or embedded in a Group arrangement for the Section.

```
Section(header: HStack { Text("Recent"); Spacer(); EditButton() }) {

    ForEach(locationsList, id:\.self) { location in

        Text("\(location.name)")

    }.onDelete(perform: deleteLocation)
}
```

Does anyone have any reasoning why my ForEach loop wouldn't be responding to the button when it's embedded in a view arrangement such as an HStack, VStack, or even a ZStack? Is there an alternative to achieve the same layout for the header without using an HStack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it's because `EditButton` is inside list. It works if to move `EditButton` out of `List`, like below

[image]

```
VStack {
    HStack { Text("Recent"); Spacer(); EditButton() }
        .padding(.horizontal)
        .background(Color(UIColor.systemGray3))
    List{
            ForEach(locationsList, id:\.self) { location in
            ...
```

Comment: Good suggestion thanks! I guess doing a VStack with Lists is better than Form/Section for this particular scenario.

Answer (score 1):

The `EditButton` presumably writes to the binding that gets handed down to it in the form of the environment value `editMode`:

```
var editMode: Binding<EditMode>? { get set }
```

The `Form`/`List` possibly manages its own `EditMode` state, a binding to which is propagated to all of its child `EditButton`s via the environment, except that for some reason an intermediary `Z/V/HStack` interferes with this propagation. Instead use your own state:

```
@State var editMode: EditMode = .inactive

...

  Form {
    Section(header: HStack { 
      Text("Recent")
      Spacer()
      EditButton().environment(\.editMode, $editMode) 
    }) {
      ...
    }
  }
  .environment(\.editMode, $editMode)
```

The `Form` now has the same `editMode` environment as the `EditButton`, bypassing any `HStack` quirks. I'm guessing that `Form`/`List` simply honors the `editMode` passed to them as long as it's not `nil`, or something like that.

The upside with doing it this way is that you don't have to change your view hierarchy.